# MySQL left join - PHP Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM product_suplier LEFT JOIN furnizor ON furnizor.id_furnizor=product_suplier.id_furnizor WHERE product_suplier.id_product=$_GET[id])";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        while($row_furnizor = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row_furnizor['name'].' - adresa: '.$row_furnizor['adresa']; }
```

PHPMyadmin result is:

nr_id ...|...   id_product  ...|... id_suplier  ...|... id_suplier  ...|...name     ...|... adress

2   .........|...  2    ..................|...1     ...................|....1   ...............|... Calvin .|... Amsterdam
3 .........|... 2 ..................|...    2 ..................|...    2 ...............|...   Care    ...|... London

Error:  Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object

Comment: Your query is failing for some reason. Check the column names (do you mean `supplier` instead of `suplier` for instance.) it stricke me right off the bat that `$_GET[id]` is wrong as it needs quotes surrounding the identifier. Please add error checking to your SQL statements.

Comment: You have a `)` at the end of your string and not a closing `"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update this line to be:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM product_suplier LEFT JOIN furnizor ON
furnizor.id_furnizor=product_suplier.id_furnizor WHERE 
product_suplier.id_product=".mysqli_escape_string($_GET['id']);
```

you call `$_GET` array values in invalid way, also remove `)` and you should use `mysql_escape_string` function when you get data from the user to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: @Dagon I already explain the different between his code and my updates

Comment: well actually the issue is the `)` the id is valid but dangerous practice

Comment: Inside a double quoted string The syntax `"product_suplier.id_product=$_GET[id]"` strangley enough is valid. It was news to me until a few days ago as well

Comment: Its getting worse: Now you are using `mysql_escape_string()` when the OP is using `mysqli` or `PDO` but is unlikely to be using `mysql` Add an `i` to that

Comment: @Dagon I explained the issues, any thing else - I with you to learn more about standards why not?

Answer (score 1):

The main issue perhaps was the lack of quotes around the GET variable name - though there were no logical tests to decide whether to process a recordset. You may also find it easier to assigna table alias when joining tables as it makes the sql easier to read IMO.

```
<?php

    /* only proceed if there is an `id` ~ the $_GET variable required quotes */

    $id=isset( $_GET['id'] ) && !empty( $_GET['id'] ) ? strip_tags( trim( $_GET['id'] ) ): false;

    if( $id ){

        /* prepare the sql ( not prepared statement )*/
        $sql = "select * from 
            `product_suplier` p
            left outer join `furnizor` f on f.`id_furnizor`=p.`id_furnizor`
            where p.`id_product`='{$id}'";
        /* Assign a result to the query */
        $result = $conn->query( $sql );

        /* logical test on the query result - only proceed if it succeeded */
        if( $result ){

            /* Personal preference: using object notation rather than array */
            while( $rs = $result->fetch_object() ) {
                echo $rs->name.' - adresa: '.$rs->adresa; 
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Just a small point: [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) does an implied `isset()` and as long as the variable cannot validly contain NULL or FALSE is good enough on its own